# How to take prior row value and use as an input to calculate the current row value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, shift

Seeking some assistance if I may.

I have the following table which i am seeking to replicate in pandas.

Column B is just a random float (i know how to generate this).

Column A is dependent upon column B, for example A2 = A1 * B2. A3 = A2 * B3 and so on.

I'm effectively taking the prior value in column A, and multiplying it by current value in column B to generate current A.

If somebody could show me how to achieve this i would be most grateful. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: that excel you have, copy the range from A1:B5 paste it in place of your image as text, then create another version of that same excel with your intended output and paste it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let do math first

```
A2 = A1 * B2
A3 = A2 * B3 = A1 * B2 * B3
A4 = A3 * B4 = A2 * B3 * B4 = A1 * B2 * B3 * B4
```

Then this is `cumprod`

```
s=pd.Series([0.9791,1.0019,1.0082,0.9975])
10*s.cumprod()
0    9.791000
1    9.809603
2    9.890042
3    9.865317
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks Yoben. If i wanted to add the output of your cumprod() calc as another column - say "adjusted A", how would you do this? Apologies, a real novice here!

Comment: df['A adjusted']=df.B.fillna(1).cumprod()*10 @PaulAllen

Comment: Yoban, in my pandas DF cell B1 actually has a value and is not blank (but is not used - it just happens to be auto populated) so the fillna is not required. I have used your code however and come up with the following that appears to work: df['A adjusted'] = df['A'].iloc[0]*(df['b'].iloc[1:]).cumprod()